# Celery exiting with Signal 11

Tags: celery

We are using following

```
OS Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
celery==3.0.24
django-celery==3.0.23
billiard==3.3.0.18
```

We have some tasks which are failing with “Existed with Signal 11”, below is a copy of the log file.

celery is running using supervisord instance with following setup

```
manage.py celery worker -E -B --loglevel=info
```

Please advise, what could be causing this to happen? and how can I debug for root cause?

```
[2014-07-02 15:00:44,765: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'Worker-2' pid:23317 exited with 'signal 11 (SIGSEGV)'
[2014-07-02 15:00:44,797: ERROR/MainProcess] Task mbox.retrieve_by_message_id[e70fc4f9-585e-4993-a43b-35942052bf2a] raised unexpected: WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: signal 11 (SIGSEGV).',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/paribus/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1170, in mark_as_worker_lost
    human_status(exitcode)),
WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: signal 11 (SIGSEGV).
```

Comment: signal 11 has nothing to do with celery. Try executing the code inside the task separately.

Comment: Any good fix to that issue?

Comment: Yet, it is related somehow according to our usecase (if anyone can help in that, please do), 
>> When we run SQL commands, like: video = Video.objects.get(pk=1) in the Python view, it works without any issue. Yet, if started in the method defined as celery's @shared_task, it dies and kills Python with ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-7' pid:25512 exited with 'signal 11 (SIGSEGV)'
more at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73265748/accessing-postgres-db-in-redisrabbitmqcelery-kills-python-task-with-signal-11

Answer (score 0):

According to our usecase the same code is killed when run from Cellary task and not when run from Python View

> > When we run SQL commands, like: video = Video.objects.get(pk=1) in the Python view, it works without any issue. Yet, if started in the method defined as celery's @shared_task, it dies and kills Python with ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-7' pid:25512 exited with 'signal 11 (SIGSEGV)'

More at (if anyone can help in that, please do):
[Accessing Postgres DB in REDIS+RABBITMQ+Celery kills Python task with 'signal 11 (SIGSEGV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73265748/accessing-postgres-db-in-redisrabbitmqcelery-kills-python-task-with-signal-11)