# Accessing Postgres DB in REDIS+RABBITMQ+Celery kills Python task with 'signal 11 (SIGSEGV)

Tags: python, postgresql, macos, rabbitmq, celery

When we run SQL commands, like:
`video = Video.objects.get(pk=1)` in the Python view, it works without any issue.
Yet, if started in the method defined as celery's `@shared_task`,
it dies and kills Python with
`ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-7' pid:25512 exited with 'signal 11 (SIGSEGV)'`

The same issue happens on two independent Mac ARM M1 and M2 environments, while the same code running on two older Macs works without any issue.

## Tried solutions

- I've tried downgrading Postgres to an older version
- I've tried to raise memory limitations, by creation of `/private/etc/sysctl.conf` and setting it like this:

```
kern.sysv.shmmax=8194304
kern.sysv.shmmin=1
kern.sysv.shmmni=128
kern.sysv.shmseg=128
kern.sysv.shmall=8024
```

according to:
https://pgsql-admin.postgresql.narkive.com/cUOCGZFR/postgresql-server-terminated-by-signal-11#

> I think you are most likely running out of memory or running up
> against a ulimit on memory. I would first check my ulimit settings on
> the postgres user and see if they are a bit small.

Yet nothing helped.

## Environment

### ISSUE-CAUSING:

most of the components are installed as latest (Aug 2022)

- MacOS Monterey, 12.4; Chip Apple M2
- Python 3.8.9
- RabbitMQ 3.10.7
- Redis server v=7.0.4 sha=00000000:0 malloc=libc bits=64 build=ef6295796237ef48 (with redis python package 4.3.4)
- Celery python package 5.2.7
- Postgres, original version was 14.4, downgraded to 12

### Fine-working:

- MacOS Monterey, 12.4; MacBook Pro (early 2015, Dual-Core Intel Core i5)
- Python 3.9.13
- RabbitMQ 3.10.6
- Redis server v=7.0.3 sha=00000000:0 malloc=libc bits=64 build=b50a789ee26ce984 (with redis python package 4.3.4)
- Celery python package 5.2.7
- Postgres, original version was 14.4

Comment: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/5867#issuecomment-564581217  says downgrading to 11 helped (back in 2019)

Comment: thanks, I've tried downloading to 11 too,  yet the same issue persists :(

Comment: Maybe ping this issue on github?: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/7007   Then they might have a change of fixing the issue withing 1 year after that was posted (which is `Oct 26, 2021`).... 